# swift 4 post notification userInfo with mixed types (string and NSMutableArray)

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I just started learning swift today.  Im trying to post a notification that has both [String, String] data and [String, NSMutableArray] data.  I get an error that says:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' to expected argument type [AnyHashable : Any]?
```

Ive tried to find a solution or similar code but have not been able to understand the problem yet.  Can someone tell me what the real problem is?  I suspect is has something to do with mixing my dictionary value types.  If so, how is this done in swift?

```
        var dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict["status"] = "ok"
        var list = NSMutableArray()
        list.add("this")
        list.add("is")
        list.add("a test")
        dict["list"] = list

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("testing"), object: nil, userInfo: dict) <--- error
```

error points to the 'dict' variable in the post notification line

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `NSMutableDictionary` as the `userInfo` type. Nor should you be using that (there's precious few reasons to use `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray` in Swift). Say `var dict: [String: Any] = [:]` instead (or `let dict = […]`). Similarly, `list` should be type as `[String]` rather than `NSMutableArray`.

```
let dict = ["status": "ok",
            "list": ["this", "is", "a test"]]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("testing"), object: nil, userInfo: dict)
```